# ivy-switch-buffer, Narrow Results

Tags: ivy

When I C-x b with ivy-switch-buffer, I see that I have a README.md on line 6.

If I enter md, I see that the README.md is now on line 13.

How can that be?

The first results are nonsensical, like helm-mode-magit-show-commit; why would it show that before my README.md file, which I had opened like 1 minute ago?

Is there a way to prioritize recent files here or something?;)